# The reciprocity law for the Jacobi-Dirichlet Symbol

Tags: nt.number-theory

The Jacobi-Dirichlet symbol $\left(\frac{z}{\omega}\right)_{JD}:=\left(\frac{ur-vs}{q}\right)$, where $\omega=u+iv$ and $z=r+is$ are any primary and primitive Gauss integers with $q=u^2+v^2$ and $t=r^2+s^2$ and $\left(\frac{}{}\right)$ as the usual Jacobi symbol, has the following reciprocity law $\left(\frac{z}{\omega}\right)_{JD}=\left(\frac{\omega}{z}\right)_{JD}$.

How can we prove this? It is straightforward to see that $\left(\frac{z}{\omega}\right)_{JD}\left(\frac{\bar{z}}{\omega}\right)_{JD}=\left(\frac{t}{\omega}\right)_{JD}=\left(\frac{t}{q}\right)=\left(\frac{q}{t}\right)=\left(\frac{\omega}{z}\right)_{JD}\left(\frac{\bar{\omega}}{z}\right)_{JD}$, where $\bar{y}$ denotes the conjugate of $y$. But I am stuck at further reducing the conjugate part in the equation. This is Exercise 8 of Chapter 3 in Iwaniec and Kowalski's book ‘Analytic Number Theory’, on Page 56.

Comment: What does the D in JD stand for, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: presumably, it's an abbreviation for both names Jacobi-Dirichlet.

Comment: @M.G., OK, but then what is JD'?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: My understanding of the notation is that JD are simply the first letters of the family names of the two mathematicians, i.e. J stands for Jacobi and D stands for Dirichlet, respectively, so JD summarily stands for Jacobi-Dirichlet. It seems like a variation of the Jacobi symbol (which is a Dirichlet character). I guess the naming scheme wanted to reflect this somehow.

Comment: @M.G., OP uses JD, but also uses JD', and now that (thanks to you!) I know what JD is, I still don't know what JD' is. So far as I know, Dirichlet' is not the name of a mathematician.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: oh, sorry, I feel so silly now, I didn't register the apostrophe in your prevoius comment. The apostrophe in OP's post looks to me like a comma before *where* now that I had a second look. I'll have a look at the latex part. **EDIT:** It's indeed a comma, not an apostrophe :-)

Comment: @M.G., my turn to feel silly, for not looking at the source code. I thought there was another apostrophe at the end of the first paragraph, but that one is a period. Interesting unintended TeXnical consequences!

Comment: @GerryMyerson: It feels like there is a good associativity joke somewhere hidden in the whole story :-)

Comment: Haha that's interesting and sorry for the confusion! I will pay more attention to avoid such LaTex's traps in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This symbol was used as an integral part of the argument by Friedlander and Iwaniec in their seminal paper *The polynomial $X^2 + Y^4$ captures its primes*. For simplicity, we assume both $q,t$ are odd. Observe that

$$\displaystyle wz = (u + iv)(r+is) = (ur - vs) + i(us + vr) = zw.$$

Hence

$$\displaystyle \left(\frac{z}{w} \right) = \left(\frac{ur - vs}{q} \right)$$

and

$$\displaystyle \left(\frac{w}{z} \right) = \left(\frac{ur-vs}{t} \right).$$

Since $q,t$ are odd and are norms in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, *every rational prime factor of $q,t$ must be congruent to $1 \pmod{4}$*, which means we have *perfect quadratic reciprocity* in the sense that

$$\displaystyle \left(\frac{ur-vs}{q} \right) = \left(\frac{q}{ur - vs} \right)$$

and

$$\displaystyle \left(\frac{ur-vs}{t} \right) = \left(\frac{t}{ur - vs} \right).$$

It follows that

$$\displaystyle \left(\frac{w}{z} \right) \left(\frac{z}{w} \right) = \left(\frac{qt}{ur - vs}\right) = \left(\frac{(ur-vs)^2 + (us + vr)^2}{ur - vs} \right) = 1,$$

which is what we wanted to prove.

In my recent paper *[Prime values of $f(a,b^2)$ and $f(a,p^2)$, $f$ quadratic](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.04136)* (to appear in Algebra and Number Theory) I generalized this identity significantly, to apply for arbitrary ideal numbers of an arbitrary quadratic field.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful answer! Writing out qt as the sum of 2 squares does the job!